# Azure ARM templates for Web App do not properly configure resources they're exported from

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

## Summary

- The ARM template exported from a working Azure Web App (for a QnAmaker Chat Bot) is not correctly exported, i.e does not completely recreate the resource it was exported from.
- Several configuration parameters are not included in the downloaded ARm template  (i.e QnAmaker connection parameters)
- This means when the Web App is deployed from the downloaded ARM template it does not restore the Web App correctly.

I've copied the ARM template here: https://gist.github.com/archmangler/165fb1c0b96dd98bbca09b9377b6293f

## Questions

- Is there a way to export the *complete* arm template such that it actually produces a functioning web app?

## Troubleshooting

1.

Analysis of differences between the configuration of working Web App resource (from which ARM template was originally exported) and broken Web App resource (created from the exported ARM template) doesn't show much:

https://gist.github.com/archmangler/9975ecdda75e8c14a26dc4f4c5f167d3

2. Using recommended sample ARM template from the Azure samples does not produce a working bot: The Bot and the App Service are not connected / associated leading to a bot which doesn't response:

Details: https://gist.github.com/archmangler/30a7d7e2260dff4b725625d6802c63f1

Answer (score 1):

this is expected, export resource to the template doesn't actually give you a 100% reliable working copy. not all of the resources can be exported, not all of the properties get exported for the resources that actually get exported.

Your best bet is just looking at the API response for the GET request for the resource and putting that in the template. Although, it will be complicated for the App Services, because they have tons of settings

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid. The settings are so complex that rebuilding this arm template via API inspection is the equivalent in effort of just writing a chat application in python using a convenient library. Very not-user-friendly. Is there perhaps an az cli based method for doing this which would avoid the use of ARM templates?

Comment: well, the trick is to always start with infrastructure as code, so you don't find yourself in this situation. unfortunately there's no easy way of solving this

Comment: There is no way to use Azure's QnAmaker + Web Chat Bot framework without  portal interaction. This component particularly (Web App) has no way but ARM template, which is incomplete itself. This means an  end-to-end IAC implementation is not currently possible.

Comment: you can deploy app service using 10 different ways at least. anything is a rest call after all*. qnamaker has an api as well. sure it would be a lot harder to start off with that, but there's no real alternative. you'd have to go through that either way.

Comment: Is there any documentation from Azure/Microsoft on how to do this?

Comment: not sure which part you are asking about, so for app services: azure powershell, az cli, templates, sdks, rest apis. for the qnamaker, not sure about qnamaker, didnt really use that. its part of cognitive services

Comment: I did a get of the configuration of the web app from a working deployment and compared it to a non-working deployment from an ARM template I pulled. There are almost no differences in the GET response for the two. Which leaves me wondering if there's any other way to check: https://gist.github.com/archmangler/9975ecdda75e8c14a26dc4f4c5f167d3

Answer (score 1):

There are some [known limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal) on the export template feature. I would recommend you to take templates for desired services from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates) and then just copy the values and fill extra settings that are not included in the template.

Comment: Could you perhaps recommend which of those example templates would best fit this one I have exported: https://gist.github.com/archmangler/165fb1c0b96dd98bbca09b9377b6293f ... ?

Comment: Have a look to this sample available - https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot/DeploymentTemplates/

Comment: Also you have more templates available on the root folder - https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore

Comment: But mainly you need to include resources for your bot service and for your web app. then you just tweak the parameters section to include your parameters

Comment: I tried the ARM template sample you proposed. It deployes a bot and a web app but the bot doesn't seem associated to the web app like it is when you create it via the portal. I suspect the ARM samples don't work. Tests added here  https://gist.github.com/archmangler/30a7d7e2260dff4b725625d6802c63f1